# Count items in list with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, linq

I have a list and each item on the list has an ID, Name, and Rank.  Is there a way to count how many times a name has a rank of 1-7 and organize so that Name shows and how many times it appears in each rank?

```
Sample Data:
ID          NAME          RANK
123         ENGL 103      1
456         CPSC 105      1
123         ENGL 103      2
789         CHEM 120      4
```

I am getting the above data with a simple SQL query.  If perhaps this could be done better in SQL I am ok with that as well.

```
Expected result:
NAME     RANK1  RANK2  RANK3  RANK4  RANK5  RANK6  RANK7  
ENGL 103  1       1     0       0     0      0      0
CPSC 105  1       0     0       0     0      0      0
CHEM 120  0       0     0       1     0      0      0
```

Comment: Simply `GROUP BY`? Some more sample table data and also the expected result would make things clearer.

Comment: hmm if you have it in sql, leave it that way, and call the results through a stored proc. if you do it in LINQ, it will prep the query, pull the data from sql to the app, then filter. it would be more lightweight to let sql deal w/ the query and simply give you the result set.

Comment: @AlexMoreno If they use EF then the entire Linq query should be translated to SQL (unless they're using Core before version 3 which might run stuff on the client when you don't expect it to)

Comment: @juharr it depends. the thing is it will also pull related data because of lazy loading. so if theres FK relations, it will pull more then it needs. thats also why i recommend doing Straight SQL then pulling it in as a stored proc. then you can stick to SQL and make the app more light weight

Comment: @AlexMoreno If you use a Select with Linq then the generated query will only pull the required columns.  Granted you might be more inclined to just pull entire entities, but nothing stops you from being lazy with your SQL and just always doing `Select *`.

Comment: @juharr I think you misunderstood. What I meant is that you should ideally use straight sql. then pull it in as a stored proc and map it as a better way of handling statements like this. Also by Lazy Loading, EF tends to pull related data to the result set you're using. https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those result with the following Linq

```
var results = data
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Name = grp.Key,
        Rank1 = grp.Count(x => x.Rank == 1),
        Rank2 = grp.Count(x => x.Rank == 2),
        Rank3 = grp.Count(x => x.Rank == 3),
        Rank4 = grp.Count(x => x.Rank == 4),
        Rank5 = grp.Count(x => x.Rank == 5),
        Rank6 = grp.Count(x => x.Rank == 6),
        Rank7 = grp.Count(x => x.Rank == 7)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Once you group the data on the `Name` you can then count how many in each group has each of the `Rank` values you are interested in.

Comment: You are my hero.  Do you know any good resources to learn LINQ?  I'm at a beginners level and I've never seen grp used before.

Answer (score 0):

```
list
   .Where(item => item.Rank >= 1 && item.Rank <= 7)
   .GroupBy(item => item.Name)
   .Select(item => new { Name = item.Key, Count = item.Count() });
```

or

```
list
   .Where(item => item.Rank >= 1 && item.Rank <= 7)
   .GroupBy(item => item.Name)
   .Select(item => new { 
        Name = item.Key, 
        Rank1 = item.Count(p => p.Rank == 1),
        Rank2 = item.Count(p => p.Rank == 2),
        Rank3 = item.Count(p => p.Rank == 3),
        Rank4 = item.Count(p => p.Rank == 4),
        Rank5 = item.Count(p => p.Rank == 5),
        Rank6 = item.Count(p => p.Rank == 6),
        Rank7 = item.Count(p => p.Rank == 7),
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle it is simple pivot:

```
select * 
  from (select name, rank from tbl)
  pivot (count(1) for rank in (1 r1, 2 r2, 3 r3, 4 r4, 5 r5, 6 r6, 7 r7))
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8ebff7ba130e1af7b72813c72174ca9f)</sup>**